# Gradle - how to run exec in tty?

Tags: gradle, exec, tty

For some few days I've got a little issue with Gradle. When I'am running Gradle build from tty (for example in iTerm with oh-my-zsh), in which I'am invoking some other console commands, I was expecting that all invoked processes will be running also in this tty... But they are not! The output from such process is not even colored...
Invoking:

```
exec {
    commandLine "tty"
}
```

produces output like: "is not a tty". Have anyone idea, how to fix that?

Comment: Have you managed to find a work around for this yet? :(